# Function fnIsDataTable is always returning false

Tags: datatable

I am using datatable version 1.9.4. Using datatable's fnIsDataTable function I need to check if data table is already initialized or not. But using fnIsDataTable function always returning false. Below is my function:

```
function getData() {
    if ( $.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable( "#example" ) ) {
        $("#example").dataTable();
    } else {
        $("#example").dataTable( {
            bLengthChange": false,
           "bFilter": true,
           "bInfo": false,
           "bSort": false,
           "iDisplayLength": 50
        } );
    }
}
```

Can someone help me in this?

Answer (score 3):

I found the solution. We need to get reference of that table element by using javascript function getElementById and then use this reference variable in fnIsDataTable function to check its initialization. Like below:

```js
function getData() {
  var ex = document.getElementById("example");
  if ( $.fn.DataTable.fnIsDataTable( ex ) ) {
    $("#example").dataTable();
  } else {
    $("#example").dataTable( {
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bFilter": true,
      "bInfo": false,
      "bSort": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 50
    } );
  }
}
```

Comment: If you already have the jQuery node, you can use: `var ex = $("#example")[0]` to get the HTML node

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, since v1.10, you can simply use `isDataTable` instead of `fnIsDataTable`.

```js
function getData() {
  if ( $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( "#example" ) ) {
    $("#example").dataTable();
  } else {
    $("#example").dataTable( {
      "bLengthChange": false,
      "bFilter": true,
      "bInfo": false,
      "bSort": false,
      "iDisplayLength": 50
    } );
  }
}
```

See documentation: https://datatables.net/reference/api/%24.fn.dataTable.isDataTable()

Comment: He is using v1.9.4, `isDataTable()` was added with v1.10.